# Setting up react native with woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, react-native, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

i am trying to set up woocommerce with react native but i dont seem to be able to make it work. i tried installing npm installing woocommerce but i keep getting crypto errors ive tried installing crypto but this didnt change anything what am i doing wrong?

[image: this is the error messsag]

this is my Api.js

```
var WooCommerceAPI = require('woocommerce-api');
var Api = new WooCommerceAPI({
url: 'http://localhost/wordpress/',
consumerKey: 'ck_131767da20304ce21b86f593273c989ac2cffa0b',
consumerSecret: 'cs_416f6ccbf56bb77f36553acbe77bbae619ab4571',
ssl: true,
// version: 'wc/v2'});
```

Comment: The error clearly says `module` missing. So, first thing you can do is install that module anyway possible.

Comment: If I'm not wrong I had to put this line in order to make it work
  `wpAPI: true,
  per_page: 20,
  version: 'wc/v2',
query_string_auth: true`